# Developer Component Stay Active

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I do and did some test from VSCODE with yo Office.

After few tests, Excel Developer Component displays this :

[image]

All the corresponding projects have been deleted. But menu options still remains and still work.

I'm looking for remove them.

I followed all recommandation from this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache... but nothing happened.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On the web, the office cache is just the browser cache. You need to clear the browser cache along with Office cached folder. See how to [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already did every step of this process. But, no result.

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache which is not described in the article.?

Comment: yes i did... even i still didn't understand the link it exists with native app